# Rails nested model validation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms

I have the following Recipient model containing some validations (just showing the first 2 to keep it simple):

```
 class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :offer
  belongs_to :offer_acceptance
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :aba_transit_number, presence: true, aba_checksum: true, format: { with: /\A((0[0-9])|(1[0-2])|(2[1-9])|(3[0-2])|(6[1-9])|(7[0-2])|80)([0-9]{7})\Z/, message: "has an invalid format" },  if: "to_usd?"

  def belongs_to_offer?
    #Check if recipient is from offer
    offer_id != nil && offer_acceptance_id == nil
  end

  def to_usd?
    (belongs_to_offer? && offer && offer.currency_to === "usd") || (!belongs_to_offer? &&  offer_acceptance && offer_acceptance.offer.currency_from === "usd")
  end
...
```

And here is the Offer model

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :recipient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipient
  validates_associated :recipient
  ....
```

As you can see, the `aba_transit_number` validation only takes place if the `recipient.offer.currency_to === "usd"`.
The validation works fine when I create a new recipient on the console like so:

```
o = Offer.create!(currency_to: "usd")
r = Recipient.create!(offer: o, name:"John")
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Aba transit number can't be blank, Aba transit number has an invalid format, ...
```

But when I try this from a nested form, the only validation that takes place on the recipient is the name validation. I figured the reason is that `to_usd?` returns false because since the offer has not been created yet, there is no offer_id or offer_acceptance_id.

Is there a way to let the Recipient model know that the record is being saved by an offer with currency_to set to "usd" for example? This is, can parent attributes be passed to the child model when created in a nested form?

Comment: The reason why I'm checking `offer.currency_to` is because there are different validations that depend on that field. Some validations apply if that value is "USD", others if it is "CNY", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the only thing that needed to be done was to add the association on the offers#create action

```
@recipient = Recipient.new(offer_params[:recipient_attributes])
@recipient.offer = @offer
```